# Print a div as PDF in lightning

Tags: lightning

I am trying to print a PDF on a Lightning page using the jsPDF library.
A first problem is that when wanting to execute the following code, it tells me that the 'save' function is not defined.

> var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4'); 
>   pdf.text(20, 20, 'Hello world.');
>   pdf.output('save', 'filename.pdf');

I added the FileSaver library using the saveAs method, but it did not solve the problem either.
The same thing happens to me when I want to use other functions of the jsPDF library, such as addHTML.

Has anyone successfully tested printing part of a lightning document in PDF?

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing some PoC and I can use jsPDF to download a PDF with some text (I can't add HTML until now)

You can download and deploy it from my [git hub](https://github.com/edutrujillo/jsPDFLightning/)